# Como actualizar el mismo campo con diferentes valores de una tabla con jpa en java?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Tengo las siguientes tablas, la cuales ya hice su mapeo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
@Entity
@Table(name ="Valores", shema="USER_PU")
@SequenceGenerator(name="Valores", sequenceName="USER_PU.SEQ.Valores", allocationSize =1)
@Data
public class Valores implements Serializable{
    
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Valores")
@Column(name="ID_VALOR", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idValor;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_AJUSTE", referencedColumnName = "ID_AJUSTE", 
  nullable=false)
private Ajustes ajustes;


@Column(name="VALOR")
private Integer valor;

@Column(name="DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;

@Column(name="CANAL")
private String canal;

}




@Entity
@Table(name ="Ajustes", shema="USER_PU")
@SequenceGenerator(name="Ajustes", sequenceName="USER_PU.SEQ.AJJSTES", allocationSize =1)
@Data
public class Ajuestes implements Serializable{
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Ajustes")
@Column(name="ID_AJUSTE", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idAjuste;

@Column(name="TIPO")
private String tipo;

@Column(name="LLAVE")
private String llave;

@Column(name="VALOR")
private String valor;

@Column(name="DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;

@Column(name="ALCANCE")
private String alcance;

}
```

Lo que necesito es actualizar en la tabla **Valores** el campo **valor**, tengo un método que recibe 2 parámetros, los cuales pueden ser modificados, ya sea los 2, o sólo 1, pero cada parámetro tiene su **llave**, por ejemplo en las tablas que puse en el campo **LLAVE** están PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A y PRUEBA_MODULO_A y tienen un valor 30 y 60 respectivamente, entonces mi método recibirá los nuevos valores para esas llaves, puede que solo quieran actualizar 1 llave o las 2 y estas deben reflejarse en el campo Valor

Tengo el siguiente método pero solo actualiza el valor de una llave , como le puedo hacer para actualizar los valores de las 2 llaves si es que se requiere, o si son más campos por ejemplo 5 y puede que se quiera actualizar los 5 o solo 3, como se haria??

```html
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PruebaOperacion{

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "USER_PU")
  private EntityManager entityManager;
 
  @Interceptors(CheckpointMonitor.class)
  public void operacionActualizar(Integer componente, Integer modulo){
  
    StringBuilder updateStr = new StringBuilder("UPDATE Valores va SET ");
    updateStr.append("va.valor = :componenteParam");
    updateStr.append("WHERE va.ajustes.idAjuste =(SELECT ajus.idAjuste FROM Ajustes ajus WHERE ajus.tipo =:tipoParam AND ajus.llave = :llaveParam)");
    entityManager.clear();
    
    final Query query = entityManager.createQuery(updateStr.toString());
    query.setParameter("componenteParam", componente);
    query.setParameter("tipoParam", "NEW");
    query.setParameter("llaveParam", "PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A");
    query.excecuteUpdate();
    entityManager.flush();
  
  }
 
}
```

O de que otra manera puedo hacer esa actualización de parámetros?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes la respuesta, hay diversas maneras de realizar esto

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827236/how-to-update-two-tables-using-jpa-with-java/63039054#63039054